# Why is the output 0.0000001 too low or high everytime I use this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I created this small python program that finds the root of a number:

```
def findRoot(number):
    a = 0
    aa = 0.00
    aaa = 0.0000
    aaaa = 0.000000
    aaaaa = 0.00000000
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        if a * a > number:
            break
        else:
            a = a + 1
    a = a - 1
    aa = aa + a

    while x == 1:
        if aa * aa > number:
            break
        else:
            aa = aa + 0.01
    aa = aa - 0.01
    aaa = aaa + aa

    while x == 1:
        if aaa * aaa > number:
            break
        else:
            aaa = aaa + 0.0001
    aaa = aaa - 0.0001
    aaaa = aaaa + aaa

    while x == 1:
        if aaaa * aaaa > number:
            break
        else:
            aaaa = aaaa + 0.000001
    aaaa = aaaa - 0.000001
    aaaaa = aaaaa + aaaa

    while x == 1:
        if aaaaa * aaaaa > number:
            break
        else:
            aaaaa = aaaaa + 0.00000001
    aaaaa = aaaaa - 0.00000001
    aaaaa = aaaaa + 0.000000009375465
    print(aaaaa)
findRoot(64)
findRoot(81)
findRoot(36)
findRoot(784)
```

It worked without the numbers behind the decimal mark, with just the first few lines (it would just output 8 as root 64), but now the output is:
7.999999999999999.
Where does the 0.000000000000001 go to? And why does it work fine with 81, 36 and 784? Why don't those numbers loose 0.000000000000001 like 64 does?

Comment: It´s a general issue depending on floating points. float/double vlaues are not exact values and the CPU can´t calculate exact with it. So using `decimal` is the common way or define a rounding +- which is also "correct".

Comment: Example from java: `double a=Double.MAX_VALUE; double b=Double.MAX_Value - 1;` print both values or use `==` on a IF and you will see it´s the same because it´s not correct.

Comment: Thank you @LenglBoy , I used the round function and it worked

Comment: But so keep in mind that this woun´t be correct for calculating real things. So on Python there are `decimal` types, too. You just need to import them.